# Iterating through a dataframe is returning spaces in the string not removed with strip()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-docx

I have a dataframe where I am attempting to:
 - Get the value from one column only (the column name is 'name')
 - Print the values out as lines in a word document (not a table) without the index

I am running Python 3.7 and using the following docx modules:

- import docx
- from docx.shared import Inches
- from docx.enum.section import WD_SECTION
- from docx.oxml.ns import qn

The following code is returning the correct values, however, the word document has many leading and trailing white spaces after the first line printed that are not removed.

```
for i in Depts:
    doc.add_paragraph(Depts.name.to_string(index=False).strip())
```

Other variations I have tried in the for loop include:

```
doc.add_paragraph(Depts.name.to_string(index=False).strip(' '))
doc.add_paragraph(Depts.name.astype(str).strip(' '))
```

I've tried other variations above and beyond this including assigning the values to a variable (although in theory this probably has no merit) and then attempting another strip on the variable with no success.

```
x=Depts.name.to_string(index=False).strip(' ')
x=x.strip()
doc.add_paragraph(x)
```

I've also tried using get_value which encountered warnings regarding deprecation and was overall unsuccessful and using .iterrows() which appeared to ignore my request for specific column with no index.

Comment: `strip()` removes characters from both left and right. Use `replace(" ", "")` to remove all spaces.

Comment: Have you tried calling the default strip form, with no parameters? (just  `.strip()`)- it will remove other white-space characters beyond space (\x20)

Comment: The strings themselves also have spaces in them so unfortunately, replace is probably not a usable solution.  Strip() with no parameters has been attempted.

Answer (score 0):

This probably means the so called spaces you are trying to remove are not our regular ' ', could you explicitly print the code of that character and then pass it to the strip() function to remove it alongside the regular ' '.

Comment: Upon further tests, it looks like this spacing is the result of a right justification being output from the dataframe and putting a bunch of spaces in.  I looked at some solutions on Stack specific to this but am not finding anything that works.  Upon attempting to add in these solutions I receive errors along the lines of "Styler object not iterable".